# Poor Man's Session ID Causes Parse Error

Tags: php

I created this little guy to get large session IDs for my own purposes:

```
// returns a 1024-byte hash for session IDs

class sha512_session {

private $IDvalue = '';
private $IDMAX_SALT = mt_getrandmax();

for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    $seed   = mt_rand(100, $IDMAX_SALT);
    $IDvalue .= strtoupper(hash('sha512', $seed, false));
  }

public function getID() {
    return $IDvalue;
  }

}
```

Outside of a class context, the `for()` loop works like it should.  When I put this (working) code in the class above, PHP returns the following:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in ../sha-iterator.php on line ... ( line # for "private $IDMAX_SALT = mt_getrandmax()" )
```

So, it works fine outside a class and breaks inside a class.  Where did I mess up?

Comment: You need to put your for loop in a method, or in constructor. How are you trying to call sha512_session?

Comment: I also don't believe you can set a function to a property. They are variables inside the class. Read more about property assignation here; http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok a comment on here answered my question.  Class property initialization during declaration must be a constant at compile time, but mt_getrandmax() is runtime info, so it fails.  The correct way here is to declare the variable, then initialize it separately:

```
class sha512_session {
    private $IDvalue = '';
    private $IDMAX_SALT;

private function getRandomMax() {
    $this->IDMAX_SALT = mt_getrandmax();
    return $this->IDMAX_SALT;
}

function __construct() {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
        $this->seed   = mt_rand(100, $this->getRandomMax());
        $this->IDvalue .= strtoupper(hash('sha512', $this->seed, false));
    }
}
public function getID() {
    return $this->IDvalue;
}

}

 $sessionID = new sha512_session();
 echo $sessionID->getID();
```

Or any variation on that theme.

Answer (score 0):

The For loop must be placed within a function. I think you should place it in a constructor.

```
class sha512_session {
    private $IDvalue = '';
    private $IDMAX_SALT;

    function __construct() {
        $this->IDMAX_SALT = mt_getrandmax();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
            $this->seed   = mt_rand(100, $this->IDMAX_SALT);
            $this->IDvalue .= strtoupper(hash('sha512', $this->seed, false));
        }
    }
    public function getID() {
        return $this->IDvalue;
    }

}
```

Comment: That was exactly my first thought, and I attempted this.  The error consistently mentions the line containing the mt_getrandmax() function.  I am instantiating this class and getting its IDvalue through $object->getID().

Comment: Move your `mt_getrandmx()` function into a method. `public function getRandMax(){return mt_getrandmax();}` assuming your class can access that function.

Comment: Try above code, I moved the $IDMAX_SALT initialization into the construct function